# The quotient group (space) of $\Bbb Z/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

Find the quotient group(space) of $\Bbb Z/H$ if $H = 6\Bbb Z $ and it is also a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Do the same if $ H = \langle[4]\rangle $ in $ \Bbb Z_{12}$

The quotient group of $\Bbb Z/H$

$H = \{...,-12, -6, 0, 6, 12,...\}$

I am not quite sure what is the quotient group of $\Bbb Z/H.$

I think it is $\{[6]\}$. I only know about quotient group that is related to equivalence relation.

For $H = \langle[4]\rangle $ in $ \Bbb Z_{12}$,

$[4] = \{4, 16, 20, 24,...\}$

$\langle[4]\rangle = \{4\}$ since the remainders of $4^k$, with $k \in Z$ are always 4.

Again, I am not sure what the quotient space is here.

I am in abstract algebra and we haven't talked about topology yet.

Comment: Why do you expect this to have anything to do with topology? Look up quotients by subgroups in whatever book/notes you use.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  : May be user heard about quotient spaces in topology and getting confused with this quotient.. I guess we call this quotient group and not quotient space...

Comment: @cello Yeah, that would be more common, though in connection with equivalence relations, it is also sometimes called the quotient space.

Comment: actually, it is a question from my abstract algebra class. We have only talked about group theory and equivalence relations. The question did asked for quotient space.

Comment: So, the point here is that, (as the other user said) this has nothing to do with topology... Names are same.. Nothing more than that..

Comment: So it is the quotient group you are looking for?

Comment: @JKnecht I think the reason it is not called the quotient group here is that it just asks for it as a set, not as a group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I guess i can undelete my partial answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The quotient group of $\Bbb Z/H$

$H = \{...,-12, -6, 0, 6, 12,...\}$

I am not quite sure what is the quotient group of $\Bbb Z/H.$ "

It is the cosets of $H$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

$\Bbb Z/H = \{0+H, 1+H, 2+H, 3+H, 4+H, 5+H \} \cong \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

with addition modulo $6$.

Comment: That last equality is not technically correct.

Comment: The word technically might have been misleading. Those are not identical sets, as $0 + H\neq 0$ and so on.

Comment: No, that does not make the sets equal, that just makes them isomorphic as groups.